# What is the computationally most efficient way to show that an (n x m) matrix is full rank?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

Given a real *(n x m)* matrix *A*, with *n* < *m*. What's the computationally most efficient way to check if *A* has full row rank?

Of course, a straight-forward solution would be to use an SVD, QR-decomposition, or similar. However, in this particular case, I am not interested in obtaining the decomposed system, but only the "binary" information if the matrix is full row rank - or not.

Some background info on the general setting, if it is useful: I need to perform rank checks on a very large amount of matrices (> 10000) as fast as possible, where typically 2 < n <12 and 12 < m < 36, in an optimal control application. Although I believe this is an algorithmic question, it might be useful background information that the implementation is in C++, using the Eigen 3 library.

Thanks a lot in advance, any input will be highly appreciated!

Comment: [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) takes less time than QR, and I don't think you can get the rank substantially faster than that. Also, consider the effect of floating point operations: does the matrix `[[0.1 + 0.2, 0.3], [1, 1]]` have rank 1 or rank 2?

Comment: Although obvious, I want to also point out that it would be equally useful to have a fast method for indicating that a matrix is NOT full rank.